# How to write one IE conditional comment to target all IE versions at once?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, xhtml, internet-explorer-8

I want to use a JavaScript only for all IE version 6,7 and 8.

Comment: Adding this as a comment here because it's really not an answer: why do you want to do this? What about if Javascript is turned off? As one of those people who's forced to use IE at work, I get really pissed at sites that try to tell me my "choice" of browser is wrong.

Comment: I'm using javascript only for IE so if javascript is turned off? then it will only affect to IE. and i'm just giving progressive enhancement to IE versions

Comment: BTW i asking to use this jquery plugin http://www.malsup.com/jquery/corner/ to make corner round in all IE version without using any image. because any IE version doesn't support and css property to make round corner so i will use this plugin only for IE versions and css for others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nested conditions (**WRONG**):

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]> 

<!--[if gte IE 6]> 

<!-- your stuff here -->

<![endif]-->

<![endif]-->
```

**EDIT:**
As Martha highlighted, nested condition don't work, use " `&` ":

```
<!--[if (lte IE 8) & (gte IE 6)]> 


<!-- your stuff here -->


<![endif]-->
```

Other examples from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
<!--[if IE]><p>You are using Internet Explorer.</p><![endif]-->
<![if !IE]><p>You are not using Internet Explorer.</p><![endif]>

<!--[if IE 7]><p>Welcome to Internet Explorer 7!</p><![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7)]><p>You are not using version 7.</p><![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 7]><p>You are using IE 7 or greater.</p><![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 5)]><p>You are using IE 5 (any version).</p><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 5.5)&(lt IE 7)]><p>You are using IE 5.5 or IE 6.</p><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 5.5]><p>Please upgrade your version of Internet Explorer.</p><![endif]-->

<!--[if true]>You are using an <em>uplevel</em> browser.<![endif]-->
<![if false]>You are using a <em>downlevel</em> browser.<![endif]>

<!--[if true]><![if IE 7]><p>This nested comment is displayed in IE 7.</p><![endif]><![endif]-->
```

Comment: You can't nest regular html comments - the first 'end comment' tag will be considered the end of the comment, and everything after it will be displayed. The extra 'end comment' tags will be ignored as invalid/unknown. I don't think this is any different with IE conditional comments. (If nothing else, nesting them will make your page break in non-IE browsers.)

Comment: I wasn't aware you could nest these. Great to know. +1

Comment: @MitMaro: NO NO, see my answer again, Martha is right, you can't nest! Use " & ". :P

Comment: MitMaro, see my note above - you actually *can't* nest html comments. (IE conditional comments work because to non-IE browsers, they look like regular ol' comments.)

Comment: I think it's enough for my needs <!--[if lte IE 8 ]> <p>IE 8 and lower version</p> <![endif]-->

Comment: I like the use of " & " more, nesting seems hackish so I am happy it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this to prevent it from applying to future versions of IE

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
Content for IE less than version 9 goes here
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Its easier to read your code if you indent it at least 4 spaces so it gets put in a `pre` block.

Comment: Can we also use this <!--[if IE]> <h2>You are using Internet Explorer.</h2> <![endif]--> ?

Comment: @Jitendra, yes you can. (See my answer below. Or above, depending on how you're sorting.)

Answer (score 1):

You can target conditional comments at Internet Explorer regardless of version:

```
<!--[if IE]> IE stuff goes here <![end if]-->
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This one blew me away, but check it out:

```
var IE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;
```

[Source](http://devoracles.com/the-best-method-to-check-for-internet-explorer-in-javascript)

Comment: Sorry, just realized you wanted the conditional comment usage from your title.  *hides in shame* I'll try to read the title better next time. Good luck.  *note to self, no SO after 10:30

Comment: Is that like "no sewing after midnight"? :)