# How can I have special CSS for IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I would like to use some different CSS for ie8 but keep just the one CSS file. Can anyone tell me what the best "hack" for this is?  Yeah I know hacks are not good but I would like to keep one CSS file at least just for now.

For example, in non-IE8 browsers I would like the browser to see this:

```
div.content_header_heading { 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #cccccc 0%, #eeeeee 35%, #eeeeee 65%, #cccccc 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#cccccc), color-stop(35%,#eeeeee), color-stop(65%,#eeeeee), color-stop(100%,#cccccc)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #cccccc 0%,#eeeeee 35%,#eeeeee 65%,#cccccc 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #cccccc 0%,#eeeeee 35%,#eeeeee 65%,#cccccc 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #cccccc 0%,#eeeeee 35%,#eeeeee 65%,#cccccc 100%); /* IE10+ */
}
```

But if the browser is IE8, I would like the browser to see this:

```
div.content_header_heading { 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write one IE conditional comment to target all IE versions at once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774574/how-to-write-one-ie-conditional-comment-to-target-all-ie-versions-at-once)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Paul Irish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89484/paul-irish) has a good solution to this problem.  It involves using conditional comments to place classes on the `<html>` tag:

```html
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Then you can target IE versions with CSS rules:

```css
.ie8 div.content_header_heading { 
}
```

See http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/.

Comment: This looks really good. Anyone know how to combine this into one with an else:    
 
<!--[if (lt IE 9) ]>    <html class="ielt9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->

BTW what code is this? I am not familiar with using code this way.

Comment: I'd like to add, that you can use not class, but whole CSS file just for specific IE. Idea is the same, but you won't clutter your normal CSS file. [Take a look here](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

Comment: I only have the one place where I want the CSS to be different so using another file is kind of overkill. Thanks

Comment: @Maricel: these are "conditional comments", an IE-only feature allowing you to use HTML comments to target markup towards certain versions of IE or browsers that are not IE.  There are no `else` statements, so you cannot combine those into a single conditional comment.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have come across is using a different CSS file for the Internet Explorer.

Then in your HTML you can exclude or include them using the typical conditional code blocks you find on the internet.

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
  CSS HERE
<![endif]-->
```

Only put in those lines of CSS that need to be different in that IE version.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to make sure every html element is interpreted (at all) by the browser is to use http://www.modernizr.com/

If you want to use header, footer or other new html5 elements modernizr will create them so that old browsers understand the elements.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest CSS hacks for different versions on IE are:

```
.color {color: #777;} /* for all browsers */
* html .color {color: #C39;} /* for IE6 */
*+html .color {color: #66F;} /* for IE7 (you can also use the long expresion " *:first-child+html ") */
.color {color: #0FC\0/;} /* for IE8, going last */
```

all of the above are hacks, but at least they use VALID CSS, except the hack for IE8 where i recommend using a conditional comment.